# What is the meaning of the light red background in a question?

Tags: support, questions, user-interface

At first I thought it indicated questions I have participated in, but then I saw one of those with no light red background.

To avoid confusion, the colour is the same as the one for "Featured in Meta" which appears at the right side of the site.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are questions that feature a tag that you are watching.

In the case of the picture you provided, you can see a small eye in front of the "philosophy-of-mathematics" tag, meaning that this is the one you are watching.

This highlighting is a great way to immediately see questions that are in one's field of interest/expertise, given one watches the appropriate tags and the questions are tagged correctly.

You can see and edit the tags you watch and those you ignore (question with such a tag won't show on the main page) either on the right side (desktop version) or below the questions (mobile version):

[image]

Comment: I deleted my answer because I see it was not relevant. I hope everyone is doing well!

Comment: I saw your comment. TY. Now off to study Ivan Illich or perhaps try to extend Santayana’s “animal faith” beyond epistemology. I want to look at it as a deep human fear response to certain technologies